# how to set conditions for total or cell in cross tab in fastreport for visible or width=0

Tags: crosstab, fastreport

I have a cross tab in Fast Report 5.

I want to set a condition for column header or cells that cells visible is off.

How to set conditions which are 'visible is off' for cells?

Comment: Syntax and formatting

Answer (score 0):

You may set column width to 0 in the cross-tab OnCalcWidth event

```
procedure Cross1OnCalcWidth(ColumnIndex: Integer; ColumnValues: Variant; var Width: Extended);
begin
  if ColumnValues[0] = '2000' then Width := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Hi  my friend . tnx for question , but i want set condition for headers values no column Index  . Because changes columns value !!! tnx again

Comment: Hi dear gpi 
this is syntax not work !!! i asked question this linke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183688/hide-column-in-db-cross-tab-for-fastreport  .. very very tnx

Comment: Hi dear gpi . i am waiting for answer . tnx

Comment: Your script should works. Create a small demo project with error and attach it here or send it to support@fast-report.com