# Hide column in DB cross-tab for FastReport

Tags: crosstab, fastreport

I've been trying to hide column from a DB cross-tab in FastReport when the column header Value is 14001 ; but is not work down syntax !!!

[My Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iVib.jpg)

Here's the code:

```
procedure DBCross2OnCalcWidth(ColumnIndex: Integer; ColumnValues: Variant;var Width: Extended);
begin 
if (VarToStr(ColumnValues[0]) = '14001') then 
    Width := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Your script should works. Create a small demo project with error and attach it here or send it to support@fast-report.com

Answer (score 0):

Try add procedure trigged on print and collection HeaderValues[0]

```
procedure DBCross2OnPrintColumnHeader(Memo: TfrxMemoView; HeaderIndexes, HeaderValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if (VarToStr(HeaderValues[0]) = '14001') then
  begin
    Memo.Width := 0;
    Memo.Height := 0;
    Memo.Printable := false;
    Memo.Visible := false;                          
  end;                      
end;
```